# textview clickable without xml

Tags: java, android, click, textview

I'm trying to make textview clickable. I got 50 textview so I create them with java code. The problem is I don't know ho to make them clickable. If I'd work with XMl, it would be easy because the question has been asked a lot.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.goo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calendrier extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    LinearLayout linear;
    TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[50];
    TextView[] textViewArray2 = new TextView[50];
    LinearLayout[] layoutArray = new LinearLayout[50];
    ScrollView SV;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

        SV = new ScrollView(this);          
        linear = new LinearLayout(this);

        //Crée et Affiche les 50 textview sur lesquelles on cliquera
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
            textViewArray[i].isClickable();
            textViewArray[i].setText("Journée" + (i+1));
            linear.addView(textViewArray[i]);
        }

        //Création de 50 textview qui seront cette fois ajoutés dans leur layout perso
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            textViewArray2[i] = new TextView(this);
            textViewArray2[i].setText("Journée" + (i+1));
        }

        //Création 50 layout 
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            layoutArray[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            layoutArray[i].addView(textViewArray2[i]);
        }

        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        SV.addView(linear);
        setContentView(SV);   
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //What should I do here ?
        //I'd like if I click on the textview n°1, the layout I create before ( layoutArray[i] = new LinearLayout(this); ) appears
        if (dialog == textViewArray[0]){
                System.out.println("this text never prints :( ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget

```
textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

AND, you use the OnClickListener from DialogInterface. This is wrong. You must use the View.OnClickListener with a textview

Comment: I edited my code and i have now this:

http://pastebin.com/1N09ztjA

What am I doing still wrong ?

Comment: All is ok in your screen ? All Textview are displayed ?
Try another test method in OnClick like Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); (without any test)

Comment: Ho I had a stupid error (bad copy/paste). it Works great, thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1):

First use  [`View.OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) instead of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.
Then you can use

```
textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```